# Eigenvalues of the geodesic deviation equation, curvature invariants, and singularities

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, curvature, singularities

The geodesic deviation equation tells us what tidal forces freely falling observers experience in a local Lorentz reference frame. The tidal deformation tensor is
$$E^{\alpha}_{\gamma}=R^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma\delta}U^{\beta}U^{\delta}$$ where $R^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma\delta}$ is the Riemann curvature tensor and $U^{\alpha}$ is the four velocity along a timelike geodesic.

Are the eigenvalues of this tensor (expressed in an orthonormal basis) necessarily infinite at a singularity and bounded at a coordinate singularity? Are the eigenvalues related to scalar [curvature invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_invariant_(general_relativity)) in any way? I am particularly interested if this may be useful to characterise vacuum spacetimes.